# Free media player with VDPAU (nVidia acceleared codecs) for Windows XP

Tags: windows, windows-xp, drivers, nvidia-graphics-card, vdpau

On Linux, with the latest official binary video driver from nVidia, I can use `mplayer -vo vdpau` (and some other flags) to offload the video decoding to the nVidia GPU. Is there a free media player for Windows XP which can do the same? I have the latest official nVidia video drivers installed on the Windows XP.

VLC needs Windows Vista for accelerated video codecs, SMPlayer doesn't say that it supports them.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't seen anything running VDPAU on XP, but [Media Player Classic - Home Cinema](http://mpc-hc.sourceforge.net/) does have [DXVA Support](http://mpc-hc.sourceforge.net/DXVASupport.html) for offloading rendering to the CPU, and has its own demuxers/decoders.

Comment: DXVA is the Windows equivalent of VDPAU, and is usable by Windows Media Player as well as MPC-HC.  To be sure that MPC-HC is using DXVA if you have the Status Bar enabled (CTRL + 5 to toggle) it should say "Playing [DXVA]" when it is using hardware acceleration and just "Playing" if not.